# how to integrate functions in SwiftUI in order to create re-usable code with input dictionaries

Tags: swiftui

I want to re-use the VStack code in SwiftUI:

```
var primary:[String:String] = ["Price":"price", "Grade":"Two", "Recovery":"Three"]
var secondary:[String:String] = ["Price":"price", "Grade":"Two", "Recovery":"Three"]

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {

                List{
                    ForEach(Array(primary), id: \.key) { key, value in
                            HStack {
                                Text(key)
                                    .fontWeight(.light)
                                .padding()
                            Spacer()
                                Text(value)
                                    .fontWeight(.light)
                                .padding()
                            }
                                    
                        }
                    
                }
            }
```

The VStack works fine , but I now want to create a function or a ViewModifier or some sort in order to run the VStack twice for both arrays. I could just put the code within the loop into a ViewModeifier in this simple example, but this is not the point. I want the whole VStack to be repeatable with input variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate mentioned `VStack` into dedicated view and use it with input data, like below (tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14)

```
struct ReuseContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DictionaryView(data: primary)
            DictionaryView(data: secondary)
        }
    }
}

struct DictionaryView: View {
    let data: [String: String]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List{
                ForEach(Array(primary), id: \.key) { key, value in
                    HStack {
                        Text(key)
                            .fontWeight(.light)
                            .padding()
                        Spacer()
                        Text(value)
                            .fontWeight(.light)
                            .padding()
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: great, how do I call this?

Comment: ok, got this going . Just copied the two dictionaries into ReuseContentView and then just called ReuseContentView()